# stop all jwplayers

Tags: jquery, jwplayer

```
$('.gallery li:not(.current) a').click(function () {
    jwplayer().stop();
});
```

... works, but only for one player, if there're multiple players running in separate tabs, it won't stop them all.

How do I stop all running players?

Comment: Are all players inside containers with the .gallery class? Posting your HTML and preferably a JSFiddle would get you better answers.

Comment: tabs? as in browser tabs?

Comment: yes, they are all in .gallery tabs

Comment: you need to help us help you... we need more than this...

Comment: I understand, but its just regular jquery inline tabs that are hidden with `display:none` so the content in those tabs is always present, just hidden when tab changes. Setting up a fiddle would be too much work, but I'd have done if it helped, this is about jwplayer though, `.stop()` is not stopping all players, just the first one that was opened.

Comment: Well yes, jwplayer() targets the 1st instance on a page. You need to the player instances by saying jwplayer('player1'), jwplayer('player2'), jwplayer('player3'), etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post may solve your problem:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/javascript-interaction/24499/jwplayerstop-how-to-use-this-code-for-multiple-players/